# Unable to get System variables in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I run my spring boot application using the following command:

```
gradle -Dekiras="ekiras.com" bootRun
```

and in the spring boot application I have bootstrap class

```
@Component
public class Bootstrap implements InitializingBean{

    @Autowired private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception { 

       System.out.println("###################"+System.getProperty("ekiras"));
}}
```

and I get the output as:

```
##########################null
```

am I missing something here.

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry about how to add the properties from your build tool (gradle). You should rather focus on giving those arguments as you were be giving them in production (java -jar myjar.jar -Dekiras="ekiras.com") and put some defaults in your .properties or yaml where you can extract them in case you don't specify a parameter when you run your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
gradle -Dekiras="ekiras.com" bootRun
```

you pass `ekiras` property to gradle script itself. You can verify it with:

```
println System.properties['ekiras']
```

in the build script.

To pass a property to the application you need the following construct:

```
bootRun {
  jvmArgs = ['-Dekiras="ekiras.com"']
}
```

Double quotes `"` are rather not necessary. Of course you can pass the property to gradle script and then configure the `bootRun` block with the property read in gradle.